# android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24) returns null

Tags: android, settings, systemtime

I have the following statement

```
String value = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
```

It works fine with my Nexus 7 (Android 4.3) and my S3 (CM10.2) but it returns `null` in the emulator with Android 2.3.3.

Everything used in that statement is there since API Level 1.
Any idea why does it return `null` or how can I check the time confifguration (12/24h) instead?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
    boolean is24 = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);